# Can Best-worst (Max-diff) scaling experimental designs be blocked?

Tags: experiment-design, scales, extreme-value

To enable a large number of items to be used (i.e. generally more than 15 or 20), can Best-worst (Max-diff) scaling experimental designs be blocked for respondents? Could anyone suggest any material to read on this?

I was operating under the assumption that if a large number of items were to be assessed, a hybrid best-worst design would need to be used. For example, if 20 (or some large number) items were to be studied, then each respondent should go through an exercise where they choose some top set (to decrease the number of exercises each respondent would need to complete) from the 20 items and they perform the best-worst exercises on all items in their top set.

However, after reading Applied Choice Analysis, pg 290, the authors create a Best-worst (Max-diff) scaling experimental design with 64 items with 34 blocks. The book does not, however, go into any detail with regard to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed two or more BIBDs to do this. Other approaches are discussed in Louviere, Flynn & Marley (Cambridge U Press, 2015: Best-Worst Scaling: Theory, Methods and Applications).

Comment: Welcome to the site, @JordanLouviere. This is being automatically flagged as 'low quality' because it is so short. Can you expand it a little? How would you use "two or more BIBDs"? Why would that resolve the issue? Etc.

Comment: Wow if this is the @JordanLouviere, the creator of best-worst, thank you very much for answering my question. My employer (a 1994 PhD in Marketing from the University of Minnesota who's adviser was apparently a colleague of yours ) and I actually just received your book.